# Are singletons necessary ever? Is not simply keeping track of instantiation enough?

Tags: singleton

It seems to me that singletons enforce a single instance but why would an application that understands that there should be only on such instance even attempt to instantiate a second instance?

Answer (score 0):

I think its also about managing the single shared instance. **Synchronization** to be precise.You don't want someone to use the resource when you are using it.

Private constructor and static method simply enforces the application to do so.

A lot of developers refrain from using it since its also difficult to test and causes multi-threading issues.